# if command not working Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am making a console like program where you input text, and when you press enter, that text gets turned into the variable "code" which gets read by the if/elseif command to direct it to a certain frame. 
When I did this though, actionscript completely ignored the if and just executed what was inside of the if.

There are no errors, but there is a warning. This is my full code

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
stop();
stage.focus=textbox;
var code:String=textbox.text;
textbox.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,thefunction);
function thefunction(event:KeyboardEvent){
    if(event.charCode == 13){
    code=textbox.text;
    trace(code);
    page();
}
}
function page(){
    if(code="red"){
    gotoAndPlay(19)
    }
    else{
        gotoAndStop(1)
    }
}
```

The warning is here=

```
    function page(){
        if(code="red"){
        gotoAndPlay(19)
        }
        else{
            gotoAndStop(1)
        }
    }
```

It says: Warning: 1100: Assignment within conditional.  Did you mean == instead of =?

I then tried doing what it said, and nothing happens when I type in anything and press enter (charCode 13).

I have tried doing this with `textbox.text`instead of the variable code, and still nothing happens. (`trace(code)` works fine, so it must be something with the bottom portion, but I'm not sure)

I am new to actionscript, so I do not know how to fix this (my excuse :D). If anybody knows how, I would love to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Fix your `page()` function. It should be `code == "red`. Notice the `==`.

Comment: I did do that, but when I typed in red and pressed enter, nothing happened.

Comment: What does `trace(code);` say about it? Also in your page function what if you add a `trace("OK - I am Red");` before using `gotoAndPlay(19)` now do you get the OK trace?

Comment: it says nothing, unless I use =. If I use =, no matter what I type, it says "Ok - I am red"

Answer (score 0):

first of all, as a general rule, you should never use the assignment operator (single =) in an if statement, always use the equality operator (double =)

what you're saying right now is "if you assigned the value 'red' to code without errors, then..." which of course is always true

then, to debug your problem, try to use `trace("'" + code + "'");` to see **exactly** what your textfield contains. if you're still in doubt, convert your text in character codes and print those. Why? if there's a non-printable or non-visible character in your textfield, your *if* statement wouldn't match (think "red " == "red" > false)

my guess is that your textfield is set to multiline, so your enter key would be added to the text and break your check. set it to single line to avoid possible problems (if you do need a multiline input field, you need a smarter way to compare text, like using regular expressions and such ...)

Comment: LOL It was because it was on multi line